# C# custom attributes declaration after member

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

does anybody know whether it is possible to declare an attribute after the member instead of before as usually it is shown in the reference/code samples?

Example:

```
public class MarkerAttribute: Attribute
{
    public MarkerAttribute(): base() { }
}

public class TheClass
{
    public int PropertyWithNoAttribute1 { get; set; }

    [Marker]
    public int PropertyWithAttribute { get; set; }

    public int PropertyWithNoAttribute2 { get; set; }
}
```

Here, for various not interesting reasons, I would like to represent the same class like this (and this is equivalent to the standard representation):

```
public class TheClass
{
    public int PropertyWithNoAttribute1 { get; set; }

    [Marker] public int PropertyWithAttribute { get; set; } 

    public int PropertyWithNoAttribute2 { get; set; }
}
```

Does anybody know if there is some special syntax indication, so that the same class could be written like this?

```
public class TheClass
{
    public int PropertyWithNoAttribute1 { get; set; }

    public int PropertyWithAttribute { get; set; } [Marker]

    public int PropertyWithNoAttribute2 { get; set; }
}
```

I've tested this in the following program and unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ScratchPad
{
    public class MarkerAttribute: Attribute
    {
        public MarkerAttribute(): base() { }
    }

    public class TheClass
    {
        public int PropertyWithNoAttribute1 { get; set; }

        public int PropertyWithAttribute { get; set; } [Marker]

        public int PropertyWithNoAttribute2 { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TheClass a = new TheClass();

            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo PropertyWithNoAttribute1_Info =  a.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyWithNoAttribute1");
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo PropertyWithAttribute_Info =     a.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyWithAttribute");
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo PropertyWithNoAttribute2_Info =  a.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyWithNoAttribute2");

            object[] attributes = PropertyWithNoAttribute1_Info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MarkerAttribute), false);
            if (attributes.Length > 0)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("{0} has attribute {1}", PropertyWithNoAttribute1_Info.Name, attributes[0].GetType().Name);
            }

            attributes = PropertyWithAttribute_Info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MarkerAttribute), false);
            if (attributes.Length > 0)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("{0} has attribute {1}", PropertyWithAttribute_Info.Name, attributes[0].GetType().Name);
            }

            attributes = PropertyWithNoAttribute2_Info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MarkerAttribute), false);
            if (attributes.Length > 0)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("{0} has attribute {1}", PropertyWithNoAttribute2_Info.Name, attributes[0].GetType().Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: No, you can't. Attributes go just before the "element" you are attributing.

Comment: The answer is no.  That's not the spec for c# and the compiler will balk forever, or at least until you convince someone to add it to the language.

Comment: As the others have said this is not possible, what have you done is just adding the attribute to the property PropertyWithNoAttribute2  not PropertyWithAttribute. So if there was no members after your PropertyWithAttribute property this will not even compile.